# Is the default font in Bevy unusable?

Tags: rust, game-development, bevy

When attempting to print "Hello, world!" to the screen with Bevy, the text would not display until I imported a third-party font file and loaded it as an asset to use as the font value in the `TextStyle` value of the `Text` component. Prior to using that font, I had not explicitly specified the font; I just used the value from `Default::default()`, which is `WeakHandle<Font>(Id(97059ac6-c9ba-4da9-95b6-bed82c3ce198, 0))`. This seems to imply that Bevy is finding the wrong font or at least an unusable one by default. Is this more likely to be an issue with the font my system is offering up or with the Bevy default font functionality?

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
use bevy::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_startup_system(setup)
        .run();
}

fn setup(mut commands: Commands, asset_server: Res<AssetServer>) {
    commands.spawn_bundle(UiCameraBundle::default());
    commands.spawn_bundle(TextBundle {
        text: Text::with_section(
            "Hello, world!",
            TextStyle {
                font_size: 60.0,
                color: Color::WHITE,
                font: asset_server.load("FiraSans-Bold.ttf")
            },
            Default::default()
        ),
        ..Default::default()
    });
}
```

That code works. When I change the font value from `asset_server.load("FiraSans-Bold.ttf")` to `Default::default()`, nothing displays on the screen.

Comment: I don't really know Bevy at all, but I think the issue is that (confusingly, and without any documentation that I can find explicitly covering it), `Default::default()` here doesn't give you a "default font" but rather a "default handle to a font-typed asset"—albeit the asset is effectively "null".  Not sure what purpose this serves or why `Default` is implemented for `Handle<T>` at all (it would at least seem sensible to have only implemented it `where T: Default` or something).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Updated for Bevy 0.11

Bevy 0.11 now offers a [default font](https://bevyengine.org/news/bevy-0-11/#default-font) which was implemented [in this PR](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/pull/8445).

### Original answer (before v. 0.11)

Bevy does not offer a default font as of now.

There was [this closed PR to add one](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/pull/1790) and there are several open issues connected to this, like [this](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/issues/1017) or [that one](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/issues/1325).

That said, I think it is confusing that it is possible to do:

```rust
TextStyle {
     font_size: 60.0,
     color: Color::WHITE,
     font: Default::default()
},
```